# Quartz Job Execution From Different Packages

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having a problem where I am unable to modify an existing job. The scenario is

I have a Quartz Job X in a package let's call it as A but I need to add one more task for Job X, the implementation of the task is already written but it is in other package B. The issue is I cannot import package B to package A using import statement , because package B is out of scope and there is no event dispatcher file in package A so that the package B could consume.

Is there any way that I can bring the method written in package B to the job which will be triggered via package A ? Something like

In the job file:

```
import package B
if(x==1)
{
  Method.clearCache();
}
```

Implementing the same method in package A would not be possible as the method is clearing the cache and the cacheService has a lot of services in package B.

Note : The method which I want to bring into package A is of type void.

Thanks In Advance !

Tried creating a new package and was hoping that I could import both the existing packages A and B